# Windows phone ScrollViewer doesn't work when projection is applied

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, uwp, projection, scrollviewer

I discovered this issue in real complex project, but it's reproducible  with simple test project. So I have the test UWP page

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Height="100">
            <Grid.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection GlobalOffsetY="100"/>
            </Grid.Projection>
            <ScrollViewer
                VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Button Content="1"/>
                    <Button Content="2"/>
                    <Button Content="3"/>
                    <Button Content="4"/>
                    <Button Content="5"/>
                    <Button Content="6"/>
                    <Button Content="7"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

it works as expected in PC version, but scroller doesn't work in mobile (windows phone) version. the same story with Windows Phone 8.1
If to comment projection on parent grid - everything is ok.

Any ideas of fix or at least workaround for that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it works as expected in PC version, but scroller doesn't work in mobile (windows phone) version.

By design,if a global transform of `scrollviewer`(Projection Transform here) can't be represented as a **Matrix Transform**, the underlying layer that handles **touch interaction** can't be used.

So if you only need to apply `GlobalOffsetY` or `GlobalOffsetX`. I recommend you using TranslateTransform instead. It won't prevent `ScrollViewer` from scrolling:

```
<Grid
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
    Height="500" Width="200">
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform Y="100"/>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
    <ScrollViewer
        VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="1"/>
            <Button Content="2"/>
            <Button Content="3"/>
            <Button Content="4"/>
            <Button Content="5"/>
            <Button Content="6"/>
            <Button Content="7"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I already found RenderTransform workaround myself. Unfortunately my issue is a little bit deeper - my real project uses Xamarin.Forms. and forms rely on Projection for translation animation under the bonnet... so it's tricky. I made a customrenderer for my control overriding TranslationX/Y to use transform instead of projection, but it's not an optimal solution..  Anyways - I'm marking your reply as an answer as it gives clear description of the root of this problem and possible solution.